# Javassist reports fields are null after being initialized in constructor

Tags: java, ssl, bytecode, javassist, javaagents

Hey guys I'm attempting to intercept the load of `sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker` and add byte code to print a couple of the private fields.

Here is the code I'm attempting to add:

```
public static final String printCLIENT_RANDOM_CODE = 
    "System.out.println(\"this.clnt_random:\"+this.clnt_random);\n"
        + "System.out.println(\"this.session:\"+this.session);";
```

Here is the function that does the enhancement. `classfileBuffer` is the original byte code, `className` is the classname, and `insertAfterJavaCode` will be the above `printCLIENT_RANDOM_CODE`

```
private byte[] instrument(byte[] classfileBuffer, String className, String insertAfterJavaCode) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Attempting to enhance " + className + "...");
    ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
    cp.insertClassPath(new ByteArrayClassPath(className, classfileBuffer));
    CtClass cc = cp.get(className);
    CtConstructor[] declaredConstructors = cc.getDeclaredConstructors();
    for (CtConstructor con : declaredConstructors) {
        con.insertAfter(insertAfterJavaCode);
    }
    return cc.toBytecode();
}
```

When it runs, however, I get this:

```
Attempting to enhance sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker...
this.clnt_random:null
this.session:null
```

Why is that? If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/ServerHandshaker.java) those fields should be initialized by the end of the constructor. What gives?

Comment: Are you sure they are being initialized? They aren't initialized anywhere in the source code you linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fields you mentioned aren't initialized in the constructor. If you look at the source code you linked and search for `clnt_random` for example, you'll find that it is only set in one place: the `clientHello` method. (`clnt_random` is defined in the base class `Handshaker`, but `Handshaker` does not initialize it anywhere either).

Since `clnt_random` is an object type, it has initial value null, and it is not assigned a new value anywhere in the constructors, so it will still be null when your code is called.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find anything in the source code. It's the [Java Security Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html) that kicks in here.

As you didn't supply your own instance of a Security Manager the default is supplied. The default Java Security Manager is configured by `${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security/java.security`. Inside this file you will find the following lines:

```
...
# List of comma-separated packages that start with or equal this string
# will cause a security exception to be thrown when
# passed to checkPackageAccess unless the
# corresponding RuntimePermission ("accessClassInPackage."+package) has
# been granted.
package.access=sun.,\
               com.sun.xml.internal.,\
...
```

That's where your exception arises from.

Security Managers are a good thing. Different sandboxes require different Security Managers. There is for example a Manger for running applets safely.

Comment: As he didn't supply his own instance of a Security Manager, *no* Security Manager is supplied. And what exception?